# Attempting to add a new Contact, why do I get this error message - 'Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string'?

Tags: debugging, 4.6.0

I'm getting this error message when attempting to add a new contact in Civi 4.6:

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in krumo::_array() (line 1071 of /var/www/[myCivisite.org]/sites/all/modules/devel/krumo/class.krumo.php)

Answer (score 1):

Eileen fixed the error, see the Jira issue at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16287

Comment: This fix will come out in the next release on the 4.6.x branch.